# Replace function in Js to replace periods and comma into one hypen

Tags: javascript

I need help in javascript where the word entered can be replaced as:

```
Input - A.. BC
Output - A-BC
```

the code that i have tried is:

```
var text = 'A.. BC';
    
new_text = text.replace(' ', '-') && text.replace('.','-');
    
console.log(new_text);
```

This is not working as it is giving me the output as:

```
A-. BC
```

Comment: `&&` is a boolean operator,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use a regular expression instead. Use a character set to match one or more dots, commas, or spaces, then replace with a dash:

```js
const change = str => str.replace(/[., ]+/g, '-');
console.log(change('A.. BC'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a charater set

```
var text = 'A.. BC';
    
new_text = text.replace(/[., ]+/g, '-');
    
console.log(new_text);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try replacing all non-alphabetical characters with a hyphen with regex:

```js
const a = 'A.. BC';
const b = 'A ..BC';

// Find all non-word characters regex
const r      = /[\W]+/g;
const hyphen = '-';

void console.log(a.replace(r, hyphen));
void console.log(b.replace(r, hyphen));

// A-BC
// A-BC
```